# ACE editor - update_image_size not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, ace-editor

I use ace editor for my project - including `enableEmmet: true`.

https://ace.c9.io/demo/emmet.html

But apparently action `update_image_size` does not working, instead I receive this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'locateFile' of undefined
```

Code snippet: https://github.com/cloud9ide/emmet-core/blob/master/emmet.js#L9972-L10002

```
/**
 * Returns image dimensions for source
 * @param {IEmmetEditor} editor
 * @param {String} src Image source (path or data:url)
 */
function getImageSizeForSource(editor, src, callback) {
    var fileContent;
    var au = require('actionUtils');
    if (src) {
        // check if it is data:url
        if (/^data:/.test(src)) {
            fileContent = require('base64').decode( src.replace(/^data\:.+?;.+?,/, '') );
            return callback(au.getImageSize(fileContent));
        }

        var file = require('file');
        var absPath = file.locateFile(editor.getFilePath(), src);
        if (absPath === null) {
            throw "Can't find " + src + ' file';
        }

        file.read(absPath, function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                throw 'Unable to read ' + absPath + ': ' + err;
            }

            content = String(content);
            callback(au.getImageSize(content));
        });
    }
}
```

The log indicated `var file = require('file');` is always **`undefined`**.

If you just take a look at my problem and share a bit of your science, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ace does not hav access to the  filesystem, you need to reimplement that function, either by running something on the server or by loading the image into the browser and checking its size.